# is there any Java API to catch request and response SOAP envelops?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jakarta-ee, webservices-client

I can uses Web service client classes to obtain the result but instead of the text result i want complete SOAP message in my JavaSE program. How can I do that? Any Idea?

Comment: What SOAP library do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.
Use `Dispatch<Source>` to work on the SOAP message [JAX-WS Dispatch](http://boplicity.nl/confluence/display/Java/JAX-WS+Dispatch).
Example
**DISCLAIMER: Did not even attempt to compile the code:**

```
    //xmlString has the xml message to send to the web service  
    StreamSource xmlMsg = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString));   
    //Create URL of web service. Place your URL for WSDL
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://10.5.2.10:8080/path/service?wsdl");  
    QName serviceName = new QName("http://example.com",  "TrivialWebService");  
    Service s = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);  
    QName portName = new QName("http://example.com", "TrivialWebServicePort");  
    //Service.Mode.MESSAGE works on SOAP msg (as opposed to Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
    Dispatch<Source> dispatch = createDispatch(portName,  
                                                      Source.class,  
                                                      Service.Mode.MESSAGE);  
    //Send request
    Source reply = dispatch.invoke(xmlMsg);  
    DOMResult domResponse = new DOMResult();
    Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    trans.transform(reply, domResponse); 
    //Now use DOM APIs
```

You can also specify if you want to work on the HTTP payload (as XML) i.e. SOAP envelope or the SOAP payload i.e. the response.
You will have write code to handle the raw XML (e.g. use DOM).
You can use this api if you use JAX-WS or CXF.
For AXIS2 it is possible to work on XML as well.Just will be some specific apis
Of course there is also SAAJ you can use.

Comment: if u could write a small sample code for this class, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Which class? `Dispatch<Source>`?

Comment: Yes, about how do I use Dispatch<Source> code to get SOAP response on my console screen ? It would be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole SOAP message will be contained within HTTP request object (HttpServletRequest). This will give you headers, body and everything else.